# iOS 6 vs iOS 7 drawInRect different result

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to draw a 'wall item' for an iOS app, the problem is when I try to update the code from iOS 6 to iOS 7 (the method is deprecated in iOS 7 so I'm trying to get it up to date)

I attached a picture with the visual result in iOS 6 vs result in iOS 7.
I am new to iOS development so maybe I am missing something.

this part is called in init and in layoutSubviews:

```
if (_title != nil) {
    //
    CGFloat flTitleH = MIN(self.rcItem.size.height, MAX(self.rcItem.size.height / 3, 20));
    CGFloat flTitleW = self.rcItem.size.width - (2 * _flTitlePadding);
    //
    CGSize szTitleBoxStart = CGSizeMake(flTitleW, flTitleH);


    CGSize szTitleBox;
    if (isSystemVersionLessThan_7_0) {
        szTitleBox = [self.title sizeWithFont:self.titleFont
                            constrainedToSize:szTitleBoxStart
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    } else {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        szTitleBox = [self.title boundingRectWithSize:szTitleBoxStart
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       self.titleFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                       paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                                       nil]
                                              context:nil].size;
    }
    //
    CGFloat flTitleNewH = szTitleBox.height + 2 * _flTitlePadding;
    self.rcTitle = CGRectMake(self.rcItem.origin.x,
                              self.rcItem.origin.y + self.rcItem.size.height - flTitleNewH,
                              self.rcItem.size.width,
                              flTitleNewH);
}
//
if (_details != nil) {
    CGSize szDetailsBox;
    if (isSystemVersionLessThan_7_0) {
        szDetailsBox = [self.details sizeWithFont:self.detailsFont];

    } else {
        szDetailsBox = [self.details sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         self.detailsFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                         nil]];
    }
    //
    CGFloat flDetailsNewH = szDetailsBox.height + _flTitlePadding;
    self.rcDetails = CGRectMake(self.rcItem.origin.x,
                                self.rcItem.origin.y + self.rcItem.size.height - (self.rcTitle.size.height + flDetailsNewH),
                                self.rcItem.size.width,
                                flDetailsNewH);
}
//
```

this code is called in drawRect:

```
 // draw title
if (_title != nil) {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGRect rcTitleBox = CGRectInset(self.rcTitle, _flTitlePadding, _flTitlePadding);

    // draw title background
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.5);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [titleBkColor CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.rcTitle);

    // draw title text
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [titleColor CGColor]);

    if (isSystemVersionLessThan_7_0) {
        [_title drawInRect:rcTitleBox withFont:self.titleFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    } else {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [_title drawInRect:rcTitleBox withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      self.titleFont,   NSFontAttributeName,
                                                      titleColor,       NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                      paragraphStyle,   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                                      nil]];
    }
    //
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}


// draw details
if (_details != nil) {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGRect rcDetailsBox = CGRectInset(self.rcDetails, _flTitlePadding, _flTitlePadding);

    // draw title background
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.5);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [titleBkColor CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.rcDetails);

    // draw title text
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [titleColor CGColor]);

    if (isSystemVersionLessThan_7_0) {
        [_details drawInRect:rcDetailsBox withFont:self.detailsFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

    } else {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy] autorelease];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [_details drawInRect:rcDetailsBox withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          self.detailsFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          titleColor,       NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          paragraphStyle,   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                                          nil]];
    }
```

In this example, _title is equal to "Jurubita, KPMG..." and _details is equal to "Friday, ZF24"

iOS6: 
[image]

iOS7: 
[image]

I don't know why the text and font are different, the pictures speak for themselves. Also 'y' in 'Friday' is not displayed properly.
What is different between the two methods?